# What is the generalized definition of '<' and '>' for complex numbers?

Tags: complex-numbers

I'd expect this question to be asked here before, but I've not been able to find it.

The generalized definition of the multiplication operator for complex numbers is simple:

The product of the lengths and the sum of the angles (relatively to the $X$-axis).

But what is the generalized definition of the $<$ and $>$ comparators for complex numbers?

Comment: [related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/310931/comparing-complex-numbers)

Comment: It is not possible to extend the total ordering of the reals to the complex numbers in a way that "respects" the product of "positive" (greater than zero) values being again "positive".

Answer (score 2):

There isn't one. There is no ordering compatible with the algebraic structure as there is for the case of real numbers. (Eg because everything is a square.)

Occasionally it is useful shorthand to write $z>0$ or something similar when referring to a condition on a complex number $z$, but this means that $z$ is real and greater than 0.

Comment: Got it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One interesting partial order on $\mathbb{C}$ is the following: $z \leq z'$ if $| z | = 0$ or ($| z | \leq | z' |$ and $\arg z = \arg z'$).

Comment: I'm curious, is this useful? It is potentially confusing because of things like  $1>0$ and $-1>0$ conflicting with the usual real order.

Comment: It extends the natural order of $\mathbb{R}_+$ but not that of $\mathbb{R}$. With this partial order $\mathbb{C}$ is thought as a union of half-lines intersecting at $0$. There is a link with the notion of [inverse semigroup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_semigroup).

Comment: Could you please indicate what the link to inverse semigroups is?