# Finding an Expression for the Difference of Roots of the Quadratic Equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

Let the equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ have the roots $\alpha$ and $\beta$, then what is $\alpha-\beta$ in terms of $a$, $b$, and $c$?

Well, we may write
$$(\alpha-\beta)^2=(\alpha+\beta)^2 -4\alpha \beta$$
$$\mbox{or}\ (\alpha-\beta)^2= \left(-\frac{b}{a}\right)^2-4\frac{c}{a}$$
$$\mbox{or}\ (\alpha-\beta)^2 = \frac{b^2}{a^2}-4\frac{c}{a}$$
$$\mbox{or}\ (\alpha-\beta)^2=\frac{b^2-4ac}{a^2}$$
$$\mbox{or}\ \alpha-\beta= \pm\sqrt{\frac{b^2-4ac}{a^2}} $$
$$\mbox{or}\ \alpha-\beta=\pm\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{a}.$$

Now, I know that the true value of $\alpha-\beta$ is $\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{a}$, but what about $-\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{a}$? Should I really get this other value or have I made some mistake or should I ignore the other value?

Comment: It just depends what order you subtract the roots in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Who confirms the true value?

If $\alpha,\beta$ are real,

If $\alpha-\beta\ge0\iff\alpha\ge\beta ,\alpha-\beta=+\dfrac{\sqrt{b^2-4ca}}{|a|}$

Else $\alpha<\beta\implies\alpha-\beta=-\dfrac{\sqrt{b^2-4ca}}{|a|}$

If at least one of  $\alpha,\beta$ is complex see

1. http://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/complex_compare.shtml
2. [Total ordering on complex numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487997/total-ordering-on-complex-numbers)
3. [Comparing complex numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/310931/comparing-complex-numbers)

Comment: i.e. $\pm \frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{a}$ cannot both be true at the same time?

Comment: @SamamaFahim, When we will have $x=-x$

Comment: So we should not just write $\alpha-\beta = \frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{a}$, we should also add that $\alpha \geq \beta$, shouldn't we?

Comment: @SamamaFahim, The last part is the condition and the other condition as in the answer  :$\alpha,\beta$  must be real

Comment: What I mean is that in the solution they just pick the positive value without stating that they supposed $\alpha \geq \beta$. This *may* confuse the reader.

Comment: @SamamaFahim, That assumption should be included