# How to prove that $\sqrt{x} > x$ for any $0 < x < 1$

Tags: inequality, radicals

I want to prove that, for any x between $0$ and $1$, the $\sqrt{x}$ is bigger than $x$. Maybe it's easy and I'm not getting the point of the proof, but I tried to prove it a lots of times and I never get to something that makes it look proved.

Comment: Look at it another way. Can you show that the square is smaller than the quantity. (You are taking a fraction of a fraction)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $x<0,\sqrt x$ is imaginary. So, $\sqrt x,x$ are not comparable.

See

[Can a complex number ever be considered 'bigger' or 'smaller' than a real number, or vice versa?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1116022/can-a-complex-number-ever-be-considered-bigger-or-smaller-than-a-real-number)

OR

[Comparing complex numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/310931/comparing-complex-numbers)

OR

[this](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/complex_compare.shtml)

So $x\ge0,$

We have $\sqrt x> x\iff\sqrt x(\sqrt x-1)<0$

As $\sqrt x\ge0,$

if $\sqrt x=0,x=0$

else $\sqrt x-1<0\iff \sqrt x<1\iff x<1$

Comment: But isn't $0 < x < 1$ anyways?

Comment: @MrYouMath, anyways?

Comment: I mean it is assumed, that $0<x<1$. So the first part of looking at $x<0$ is not relevant, or did i miss something?

Answer (score 1):

As $0<x<1$ $\sqrt{x}>0$ Now devide the inequality by $\sqrt{x}$ (note that it is positive!). You will get $1>\sqrt{x}$ which is true as $x<1$.

Answer (score 1):

We want to show for $x\in(0,1)$ that
$$
\sqrt{x}>x \text{ but this is equivalent to } x>x^2
$$
well, and this is again equivalent - since we have $x>0$ - to
$$
x>x^2>0\Leftrightarrow (\text{deviding by } x):1>x>0
$$ 
which is a true statement.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\sqrt x=y\implies x=y^2$

We need $y>y^2\iff y(y-1)<0$

If $y<0,$ we need $y-1>0\iff 0>y>1$ which is impossible

If $y>0,$ we need $y-1<0\iff y<1\implies 0<y<1$